# Git Action to publish to pub.dev fails at creating credentials.json

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to use the github actions to publish to pub.dev upon a push.

I've setup the secrets, and I've setup the workflow:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Install Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: '1.9.1+hotfix.6'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: flutter pub get
      - name: Analyze
        run: flutter analyze
      - name: Run tests
        run: flutter test
      - name: Setup Pub Credentials
        shell: bash
        env:
          PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_REFRESH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_REFRESH_TOKEN }}
          PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT: ${{ secrets.PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT }}
          PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_EXPIRATION: ${{ secrets.PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_EXPIRATION }}
        run: |
          sh ./pub_login.sh
      - name: Check Publish Warnings
        run: pub publish --dry-run
      - name: Publish Package
        run: pub publish -f
```

My pub_login.sh

```
# This script creates/updates credentials.json file which is used
# to authorize publisher when publishing packages to pub.dev

# Checking whether the secrets are available as environment
# variables or not.
if [ -z "${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_ACCESS_TOKEN}" ]; then
  echo "Missing PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_REFRESH_TOKEN}" ]; then
  echo "Missing PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_REFRESH_TOKEN environment variable"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT}" ]; then
  echo "Missing PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT environment variable"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_EXPIRATION}" ]; then
  echo "Missing PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_EXPIRATION environment variable"
  exit 1
fi

# Create credentials.json file.
cat <<EOF > ~/.pub-cache/credentials.json
{
  "accessToken":"${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_ACCESS_TOKEN}",
  "refreshToken":"${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_REFRESH_TOKEN}",
  "tokenEndpoint":"${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT}",
  "scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","openid"],
  "expiration":${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_EXPIRATION}
}
EOF
```

Now when I push a change, I'm getting an error at setting up the pub credentials :

> Run sh ./pub_login.sh ./pub_login.sh: 27: ./pub_login.sh: cannot
> create /home/runner/.pub-cache/credentials.json: Directory nonexistent
> ##[error]Process completed with exit code 2.

I'm assuming that one of the directories (runner or .pub-cache ) doesn't exist, how would I be able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

As told by the error, you are facing this issue because it can't find the `~/.pub-cache` directory.
You can resolve it simply by creating this directory.

Just add a `mkdir` command before creating the credentials.json file in your `pub_login.sh`:

```sh
# This script creates/updates credentials.json file which is used
# to authorize publisher when publishing packages to pub.dev

# Checking whether the secrets are available as environment
# variables or not.
if [ -z "${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_ACCESS_TOKEN}" ]; then
  echo "Missing PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_REFRESH_TOKEN}" ]; then
  echo "Missing PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_REFRESH_TOKEN environment variable"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT}" ]; then
  echo "Missing PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT environment variable"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_EXPIRATION}" ]; then
  echo "Missing PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_EXPIRATION environment variable"
  exit 1
fi
# ADD THIS LINE TO CREATE THE DIRECTORY
mkdir -p ~/.pub-cache

# Create credentials.json file.
cat <<EOF > ~/.pub-cache/credentials.json
{
  "accessToken":"${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_ACCESS_TOKEN}",
  "refreshToken":"${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_REFRESH_TOKEN}",
  "tokenEndpoint":"${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT}",
  "scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","openid"],
  "expiration":${PUB_DEV_PUBLISH_EXPIRATION}
}
EOF
```